# How to correct syntax of my stored procedure containing group and order clauses?

Tags: stored-procedures, syntax, sql-server-2012

I've written a stored procedure containing a group and order by clause, which is different to previous procedures I created.

I debugged the error

> Incorrect syntax near ','

but going off previous stored procedures. I set the commas after each column and table name which didn't correct the syntax in order to execute.

Is there a syntax rule to follow when creating a stored procedure in terms of the placing of commas?

This is the sample stored procedure containing the clauses that `doesn't execute due to syntax error` around commas in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStatusByOwner]
   @p_Item_Owner VARCHAR(80)
AS 
BEGIN    
    SELECT   
        [Item Owner],
        [Business Name],
        COUNT([Business Name]) 
    FROM     
        ,[TestDB].[dbo].[Status] 
    GROUP BY  
        ,[Item Owner], [Business Name] 
    ORDER BY
        ,[Item Owner]
    FROM     
        ,[dbo].[Status] 
    WHERE    
        ,[Item Owner] = @p_Item_Owner
END
```

Comment: Be aware, that you are using different spelling for `Item_Owner`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **many errors** in your code...

May be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStatusByOwner]
   @p_Item_Owner VARCHAR(80)
AS 

   BEGIN     

    SELECT   
          [Item Owner] 
         ,[Business Name]
         ,Count ([Business Name]) 
FROM     [TestDB].[dbo].[Status] 
WHERE    [Item_Owner]=@p_Item_Owner
GROUP BY  
         [Item Owner]
         ,[Business Name] 
ORDER BY [Item Owner]
END
```

Some explanation:

The comma is used to separate multiple occurances of the same type like

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ...
```

- Your example has got two times `FROM` which is not allowed in one straight `SELECT`...
- `ORDER BY` must be the last
- `GROUP BY` must be the last before `ORDER BY` (unless there is a `HAVING`)
- `WHERE` is right after `FROM` (unless there are `JOIN`s or `APPLY`s

And one more point: It was much better to use a `VIEW` or an inline-function if you do nothing more than reading. A stored procedure is meant **to do** something...